# How to get intersection with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to return the matching ids in this array of objects:

```
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1"]
```

How can I return just the id with value 1 in arr?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Lodash**

Probably the most concise working solution would be using the lodash `_.intersectionBy` but that would require your `arr2` array to contain an object with an `id`:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =[{id:1}]  // <-- object with the `id`

const result = _.intersectionBy(arr, arr2, 'id');

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another way to do this with `lodash` would be via [`_.intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith) which does not require any changes on your given inputs:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1"]

const result = _.intersectionWith(arr, arr2, (o,num) => o.id == num);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea would be to provide it with a custom function to know how to compare the values between the 2 arrays.

**ES6 & Plain Javascript**

You can do this with JS only via `Array.find` if you are looking for just one item:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1"]

const result = arr.find(x => arr2.some(y => x.id == y))
console.log(result)
```

You can use `Array.filter` in the case you have more ids in `arr2`:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1", "2"]

const result = arr.filter(x => arr2.some(y => x.id == y))
console.log(result)
```

Since you have the ids in the arr you could also just use `Array.map`:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1"]

const result = arr2.map(x => arr.find(y => y.id == x))
console.log(result)
```

Another option as mentioned by `@ibrahim mahrir` would be via `Array.find` & `Array.includes`:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'Harry'},{id:2,name:'Bert'}]
const arr2 =["1"]

const result = arr.filter(x => arr2.includes(x.id.toString()))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: ... or simply `arr.find(x => arr2.includes("" + x.id))` which can be simplified even more if `arr2` contained numbers: `arr.find(x => arr2.includes(x.id))`

Comment: Sure. Good Point. Not sure how much I wanted to simplify it but will now since you mention it :)